# libxml2 HTML Parse, document from HtmlReadFile() always has a root header of (null)

Tags: html-parsing, libxml2

I'm trying to use libxml to parse through some HTML.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <libxml/HTMLparser.h>

htmlDocPtr gethtml(char *doclocation,char *encoding) {
    htmlDocPtr doc;

    doc = htmlReadFile(doclocation, encoding, HTML_PARSE_NOBLANKS | HTML_PARSE_NOERROR | HTML_PARSE_NOWARNING | HTML_PARSE_NONET);

    if (doc == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Document not parsed successfully.\n");
        return;
    }

    return doc;
}

void getroot(htmlDocPtr doc) {
    xmlNode *cur = NULL;

    cur = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);

    if (cur == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "empty document\n");
        xmlFreeDoc(doc);
        return;
    }

    printf("%s\n", *cur);

}

int main(void) {
    char *website = "http://www.google.com/index.html";
    char *encoding = "UTF-8";
    htmlDocPtr doc;

    doc = gethtml(website, encoding);

    getroot(doc);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run the program, it always prints out (null). I'm guessing that the document isn't getting parsed corrected during HtmlReadFile(), but I'm not sure how to correct it.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Ignore me, I forgot xmlNodePtr's were pointers to structs.

Comment: If anyone needed the solution, you need to dereference the xmlNodePtr cur's name entry in the struct. so it should be 

printf("%s\n", cur->name);